# Primevue DataTable loading as simple component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, performance, vuejs3, primevue

Installed completely clean Vue 3.

Just build results in 85.54 kB index.js file.
[Clean Vue3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9nhe.png)

Adding Primevue and adding demo data for DataTable into App.vue like this:

```
import DataTable from "primevue/datatable"
import Column from "primevue/column"

\<DataTable :value="products" tableStyle="min-width: 50rem"\>
    \<Column field="code" header="Code"\>\</Column\>
    \<Column field="name" header="Name"\>\</Column\>
    \<Column field="category" header="Category"\>\</Column\>
    \<Column field="quantity" header="Quantity"\>\</Column\>
\</DataTable\>
```

I haven't added any changes to the main.ts
This results in 467.25 kb index.js

Changing to unstyled in main.ts file like:

```
import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';
app.use(PrimeVue, { unstyled: true });
```

Results in 472.55 kB index,js file

My question is, why is Primevue adding additional code with a lot of CSS into index.js file even though is used as simple component.

Is there a way just to use DataTable without any additional CSS and other components included?